# How to make a row's value unique across two columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have two columns, Column A and Column B. Column A is required, and Column B is optional. If Column B is specified, I'd like to make sure that its value is not found in Column B (easy) OR Column A (seems much harder) outside its own row. Likewise, if Column A is changed, I'd like to make sure that its new value is not found in Column B or Column A, outside its own row.

So far, the closest I've gotten is the exclusion constraint, but that doesn't seem capable of comparing Column B to Column A. Is this possible outside the application layer, or am I stuck with an application layer solution?

The use case is that I'd like the following:

1. Users always have usernames, which are always unique amongst all usernames and emails.
2. Users sometimes have emails, which are always unique amongst all usernames and emails.

This allows me to know that, for example, if a user logs in with their email address I know which username is theirs. But I also want users to be able to use email addresses as usernames. And more confusingly, I'd like users to be able to specify one email address as a username and a separate email address as the email address on file.

Any pointers?

Comment: Save yourself some trouble and ditch the third constraint. That adds a huge amount of complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have one table for `users`.  This should have a unique, auto incremented user id.  You should have another table for `logins`.  This would have columns such as:

- UserId
- LoginType (email or userid)
- Name

This table has a unique constraint on `name`.  In addition, it has a unique constraint on UserId and LoginType to ensure at most one value of each for any given user.  You can add additional constraints to ensure that emails really look like emails, for instance.

If you want a separate email associated with the `UserId` for contact purposes, you can put that in the `Users` table.

The key idea:  move the confusing notion of a login to a separate entity (table) in the database.

Comment: This doesn't address the use case of the user being able to log in with _either_ their username _or_ their email, however.

Edit: Ah, I apologise, if it's a compound constraint on UserID and LoginType, with "Name" holding the actual value, then each user could have one of each. If I then query based on Name, I get the user.

Comment: @PaddyForan . . . Of course it does.  You just look up the name in the `logins` table and identify the user using the `UserId`.