# Is there a way to set two variables as unique together?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-2.x, unique-constraint

I'm creating an application that i have username and nickname for the same person:

```
username = models.CharField(
    max_length=40, unique=True, db_index=True)
nickname = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

But i need to define this two variables as unique like:

If an user A has:

```
username: bird
nickname: dog
```

and an user B try to make registration like:

```
username: dog
nickname: butterfly
```

I will not accept because `dog` is already taken. Or if an user try to put nickname as same as username.

I'm thinking to create a registration view to make this validation manually. But is there a way to make this in the declaration?

Comment: Can I ask *why* you're doing this? This feels like some weird attempt at security (the display name may not match the user name, even for the same user?), but in practice I doubt it would do much (especially since you could find user names simply by trying to register with names that don't exist publicly until you get rejected). Smells of [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040).

Comment: For the record, the weirdness of your particular need is why you're repeatedly having people suggest `unique_together`, which would forbid `(bird, dog)` from appearing twice, but not prohibit `(bird, dog)` from coexisting with any of `(dog, bird)`, `(bird, cat)`, or `(cat, dog)`. That's clearly not your need (your fields are already individually unique, so `unique_together` doesn't constrain anything that the individual unique constraints didn't constrain already), but it would help to know *why* you need this, as the answer may be a completely different solution.

Comment: Can you please explain why you need both username and nickname. I strongly suspect you're asking the wrong question here, and trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unique_together setting under Meta.

eg.

```
class Meta: 
    unique_together = [[field1, field2]]
```

In your case this would mean that bird/dog would be unique, as would bird/butterfly. dod/bird would be allowed as the fields are different from bird/dog, but a second bird/dog would not be allowed.

Comment: An answer of this form was already posted and deleted, because this doesn't seem to be the OP's problem. The OP wants `(bird, dog)` to be forbidden if `(cat, bird)` is already registered (and vice-versa), not to prohibit `(bird, dog)` while allowing `(bird, cat)`. The fields are already individually unique after all, so `unique_together` is imposing an additional constraint that couldn't be violated anyway.

Comment: Hmm, OK. Yes, that's a little odd. I suspect they're trying to solve the wrong problem ...

Comment: I understand the meaning of unique_together, but testing here, my problem is really set the nickname and username in the same set of unique variables.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Can you explain why you need to do that though. It's a very odd scenario, and I suspect your main problem is poor model design for the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

SQL isn't generally made to enforce uniqueness across two columns, so the only solution I'm aware of would be to [split this up into two tables, one for typed names, and one for all other user information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344963/364696). You'd adapt that answer to models with something like:

```
class User(models.Model):
    # Define fields aside from username and nickname here

class Name(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('Users', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    USERNAME = 'U'
    NICKNAME = 'N'
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (USERNAME, 'username'),
        (NICKNAME, 'nickname')
    )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'type'], name='unique_user_type'),
        ]

        # Alternative more concise, but semi-deprecated, approach:
        # unique_together = [['user', 'type']]
```

By doing this, you use a single shared column for all names; it's got a `unique` constraint, so no name can appear twice as either username or nickname. Similarly, the combined uniqueness constraint on the `user` and `type` fields means any given user can only have one of each `type` of name, user or nick, while the foreign key relationship means you can access username/nickname data through the `User` model, and the `on_delete=models.CASCADE` setting means that if the associated user is deleted, then so are the associated names.

Main downsides are:

1. This doesn't *force* you to create either a `username` or `nickname` for a given user; your program logic would have to ensure that a user is never (permanently) created unless both `username` and `nickname` are valid
2. Item #1 implies that you must explicitly operate transactionally, as opposed to relying on per-table insertion atomicity; when creating a new user, you'd need to begin a transaction, create the user, flush to get a valid user id, then create both names using the new user id, rolling back the whole transaction if any constraints are violated as you go
3. Inability to define different limits for username vs. nickname; since they share a field, you can't impose different length limits on each field (your wrapper code could do so, but the DB couldn't attempt to save space based on the different limits, even if you used complicated `CheckConstraint`s to impose independent limits)

**All that said, I'd discourage this approach**. If nicknames aren't security-relevant, you can allow them to overlap (StackOverflow allows this; the link to the user profile is how you tell folks apart); they don't really need to be unique at all. Usernames obviously need to be unique, but there is no need to prevent a nickname from overlapping a username if the nickname is purely for display.

Comment: Side-note: I didn't specify `db_index=True` for any of your fields because it's unnecessary; uniqueness constraints imply an index will be created to enforce uniqueness, so `name` is indexed by virtue of `unique=True`, and a combined index on `user, type` is implied by the combined `UniqueConstraint`. The only query that won't benefit from an index is looking up all names of a specific type (user vs. nick) without limiting by user, and an index on that field wouldn't help much (you're going to scan half the table with an index, or the whole table without; it hardly matters).