# Making two columns in a table unique

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

| ID | email | alt_email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc@gmail.com | 123@gmail.com |
| 2 | def@gmail.com | ghi@gmail.com |

Each user has an email and alternative email.
I want to make it so that when a user is added (or modified), the PSQL table does not allow duplicates, even between the two columns.
For example, this would not be allowed:

| ID | email | alt_email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc@gmail.com | def@gmail.com |
| 2 | def@gmail.com | ghi@gmail.com |

Because `def@gmail.com` is duplicated. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: There is no easy and reliable solution (triggers have race conditions). Best is to change your data model and store e-mail addresses in another table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344928/how-to-make-a-rows-value-unique-across-two-columns

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: it's too bad Postgres doesn't support exclusion constraints with `text[]` and `&&` ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That would require GiST index support for arrays. No ideas how feasible that is.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest alternative - without changing the data model - would be to control it within a trigger function:

Declare the columns independently as `UNIQUE`, so that there are no duplicated e-mails in the same column:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id int, 
  email text UNIQUE, 
  alt_email text UNIQUE
);
```

Create a function to check if the e-mails exists in another column:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_email() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN  
  IF (SELECT EXISTS 
       (SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE alt_email = NEW.email OR email = NEW.alt_email)) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'E-mail already exists!';
  ELSE
    RETURN NEW;
  END IF;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And finally attach the trigger function to the table

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_check_email
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON t
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_email();
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=406debf72733a49e35b2a0afe585ddd4)

Comment: The solution with triggers doesn't guarantee the uniqueness. It still allows 2 concurrent inserts with the same email/alt email to be made. You will be forced to implement some locking mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Neither unique index nor constraint will help you there.

You can:

1. Create a `INSERT/UPDATE` [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) that will check the emails. A locking mechanism must be implemented to disallow concurrent inserts/updates as checks are performed in different transactions - that may harm your performance.
2. Move your emails to separate table as this is a one-to-many relationship. On this new table (let's call it `email`) you can add a unique index or even have an email as a primary key. This is the right and most clean solution to your problem. You can create a view with a name and the columns the same as your current table to move with the change quicker.
3. Do both of 1 and 2: create the `email` table and add the trigger maintaining the records of it based on the `email` and `alt_email` values. You will have the email duplicates but you will not have to change anything in your application - all the changes go into DB schema.